# Access search form forces a parameter box

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have a search form, linked to a single table showing number of employees based on location, which is chosen from two combo boxes (State and Office)

I run a search using the code below:

```
Private Sub command90_Click()

Dim strsearch As String
Dim Task As String
'Check if a keyword entered or not
If IsNull(Me.office.Value) Or IsNull(Me.state.Value) Then
  MsgBox "Please select an office", vbOKOnly, "Keyword Needed"
  Me.office.BackColor = vbYellow
  Me.state.BackColor = vbYellow
  Me.state.SetFocus
Else
strsearch = Me.office.Value


'Task = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ((officename Like ""*" & strsearch & "*""))"


   Task = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE officename = Me.office.Value"
   Me.RecordSource = Task
   Me.office.BackColor = vbWhite
   Me.state.BackColor = vbWhite
End If

Form!office.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Before, I used LIKE * in order to find numbers of employees, but ran into trouble when offices had similar names.(Commented out above with the ')

So in order to return exact results, I decided to use combo boxes, and restrict search terms to the combo box value.
However now a box shows up saying "enter parameter", which if entered exactly, does return the exact results, but loses the convenience of combo boxes.

How can I make it so the enter parameter box does not show up,and instead the search runs using only the combo box values?

Answer (score 0):

### Concatenate the value:

```
Task = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE officename = '" & Me!office.Value & "'"
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN (Microsoft) : **[Everything About Using Parameters from Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa160564(v=office.11).aspx)**
- Allen Browne's answer here : **[Using Form Control values in Queries](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/198141-using-form-control-values-queries)**

Comment: *I was *just* gonna say that!)  :-)

Comment: Note that, especially with names, using parameters instead of string concatenation is recommended. When a name is _o'Donnel_, for example, this code will generate a run-time error.